# Clear leaflet markers in shiny app with slider bar

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm trying to build a shiny app that will only plot points on rows that have a value within the range of a slider bar. If I increase the range of the slider bar, points will be added, but points are never removed when I decrease the range of the slider bar. Below is a reproducible example of my problem.If you increase the slider bar to full range, 3 points will show up on the map. If you then decrease the range enough it will zoom in on one point, but if you zoom out you will see that there are still 3 points being plotted on a map. I thought the clearShapes or clearMarkers function in leaflet would remove these points, but it's not working. Any suggestions?

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Test"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         radioButtons("choice","Group:",choices = c(1,2), selected = 1),
         uiOutput("value"),
         verbatimTextOutput("Click_text")
      ),

      mainPanel(
         leafletOutput("Map")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  df <- data.frame(lat = c(42.34,43.65,45.26,48.63,47.65,47.52),
                   lng = c(-96.43,-97.45,-98.56,-92.35,-94.56,-95.62),
                   id = c(32,45,65,76,34,12),
                   grp = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                   val = c(1.75,2.12,3.2,3.32,4.76,4.85))

  subsetData1 <- reactive({

    df %>% filter(grp == input$choice)

  })

  output$value <- renderUI({

    sliderInput("value",label = h3("value"),
                min = min(subsetData1()$val,na.rm = TRUE),
                max = max(subsetData1()$val,na.rm=TRUE),
                value = c(quantile(subsetData1()$val,.25,na.rm = TRUE),quantile(subsetData1()$val,.75,na.rm=TRUE))) 

  })      

  subsetData <- reactive({

    df2 <- subsetData1() %>% data.frame()

    df2 %>% filter(val >= min(as.numeric(input$value)) & val <= max(as.numeric(input$value)))

  })   

  output$Map <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet(height = 1000) %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      fitBounds(min(df$lng),min(df$lat),max(df$lng),max(df$lat))

  })

  observe({
    leafletProxy("Map") %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = subsetData(),
                       lng  = ~lng,
                       lat  = ~lat,
                       layerId = ~id,
                       radius = 8,
                       weight = 10) %>%
      fitBounds(.,min(subsetData()$lng),min(subsetData()$lat),
                max(subsetData()$lng),max(subsetData()$lat))

  })

  observe({

    click<-input$Map_marker_click
    if(is.null(click))
      return()
    text<-paste("Latitude ", click$lat, "Longtitude ", click$lng)
    text2<-paste("You've selected point ", click$id)

    output$Click_text<-renderText({
      text2
    })

  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your `observe` function where you clear markers to an `observeEvent` function.

```
  observeEvent(input$value,{
    leafletProxy("Map") %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = subsetData(),
                       lng  = ~lng,
                       lat  = ~lat,
                       layerId = ~id,
                       radius = 8,
                       weight = 10) %>%
      fitBounds(.,min(subsetData()$lng),min(subsetData()$lat),
                max(subsetData()$lng),max(subsetData()$lat))

  })
```

You also have both the `uiOutput` and `sliderInput` id's as the same (`value`). You should make sure every element has a unique id. Rename one of them to something unique.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the id's should be the same since they were both building the same slider. Thanks for clarifying that. Your solution works. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @SoloAus, If this answer helped solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) using the check mark under the voting arrows. Thank you!

Comment: is there a way to do this without having to clear all the markers?